# checking permission for marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

im having a problem requesting permissions for marshmallow, I have this function

```
private void requestPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "GPS permission allows us to access location data. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
                {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

and the imports I have

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
```

I have this dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'

compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.19.0'
compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.4@aar'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1'
```

im getting

> "cannot resolve method on
>   "ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale" and in
>   "ActivityCompat.requestPermissions"

any ideas on what can be happening?

Comment: Can you include your `build.gradle` file? Specifically the `dependencies` block.

Comment: I added it to the question @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 0):

This may help. It shows how to check if a permission has been granted, and request a new permission(s) (In this case it is Record Audio and Write to External Storage)

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) + ContextCompat
                    .checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                        (MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ||
                        ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                                (MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
                    mToggleButton.setChecked(false);
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), R.string.label_permissions,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ENABLE",
                            new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                            new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                                    .WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                                            REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
                                }
                            }).show();
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                    .WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                            REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
                }
            } else {
                (function here)
            }
```

Comment: the problem is that for some reason both ActivityCompat.requestPermissions and ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale is giving me an error "cannot resolve method" @samdelong

Comment: @DiegoAndresViermaChata what version of android are you running? If i'm not mistaken I believe this way to request permissions only works on Lollipop(5.0) and above...Also, this was is not needed to get permissions, it is just how Google wants you to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I founded a solution, changed the import

```
compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
```

to

```
compile('fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

and it solved everything